# How can I Optimize while(true) for lesser CPU impact

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

This alone takes alot of CPU usage, I need it to be on constant to when the function will be called but is friendly to the CPU

```
public static void Run()
        {
            var R1 = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (Main.Process)
                    {
                       
                       
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
```

Whats the best way to Optimize this? Whenever I try to run it it immediately takes alot of CPU power even when theres no function yet.

Comment: Can you restructure it to get an event when processing is required?

Comment: Your question does not include information about what `Main.Process` is and whether that offers some waitable synchronization mechanism. If it does, then your answer is simply to use that mechanism instead of polling. So assuming it doesn't, the duplicate question is the best you're going to do, i.e. put a small delay in the loop so you only inspect the state every 100, 200, 500, etc. milliseconds rather than consuming the CPU.

Answer (score -1):

This is called an infinite loop. Unless you have valid exit point (break; statement inside the loop), this runs forever taking up your CPU as well as memory.

Comment: Yeah but whenever I try to add break; the function cant be called. I want it to be idle and just wait for the signal to do its job.

Comment: Infinite loops and "taking forever to run" are not inherently bad, nor does that inherently lead to excessive CPU usage. It is perfectly possible to have an infinite loop that uses the CPU responsibly. This answer provides an incorrect diagnosis of the problem, and fails to provide any useful, actionable advice that would actually _answer_ the question that was asked.